# Implicit resolution fails for a contravariant type with a type bound

Tags: scala, implicit, contravariance, generic-variance

The following code compiles:

```scala
class X[U, T <: U]

object X {
  implicit def genericX[U, T <: U]: X[U, T] = new X[U, T]
}

implicitly[X[String, String]] // compiles
```

When we make `T` covariant (`class X[U, +T <: U]`) it compile as well:

```scala
class X[U, +T <: U]

object X {
  implicit def genericX[U, T <: U]: X[U, T] = new X[U, T]
}

implicitly[X[String, String]] // compiles
```

When we make `T` contravariant (`class X[U, -T <: U]`), compiler fails to materilize `implicitly[X[String, String]]`. Strangely enough, it is able to materialize `implicitly[X[Any, Any]]`:

```scala
class X[U, -T <: U]

object X {
  implicit def genericX[U, T <: U]: X[U, T] = new X[U, T]
}

implicitly[X[Any, Any]] // compiles
implicitly[X[String, String]] // error: could not find an implicit value
```

I suspect that despite an explicit type annotation, type `T`, being in a contravariant position, is prematurely fixed to `Any`. Is this the expected behaviour?

Bonus point: contravariant `T` does work if we fix `U`:

```scala
class X[-T <: String]

object X {
  implicit def genericX[T <: String]: X[T] = new X[T]
}

implicitly[X[String]] // compiles
```

UPDATE1: Update after response from Dmytro Mitin:

```scala
  class X[U, -T] // same behaviour for invariant T

  object X {
    implicit def genericX[U, T](implicit ev: T <:< U): X[U, T] = new X[U, T]
  }

  implicitly[X[AnyRef, AnyRef]] // compiles

  def check[T](implicit ev: X[AnyRef, T]): Unit = {}

  check[String] // compiles
  check // does not compile
```

Comment: In Dotty 0.24.0-RC1 the code compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yPy9PxcvTHqbI4bbmxyuhQ This can be considered as a bug. Bugs should be reported here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: It's interesting that the code starts to compile if we add constraint `implicit def genericX[U, T <: U](implicit ev: T <:< U): X[U, T] = new X[U, T]`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMvOykNQ4zs

Comment: I updated the question - added example with `implicit ev: T <:< U`.