# Scala's Nothing vs partial unification

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I would expect the following code to compile just fine:

```scala
trait Widen[M[_]] { def widen[A, B >: A](ma: M[A]): M[B] }

object Widen {
  implicit class Ops[M[_], A](ma: M[A]) {
    def widen[B >: A](implicit ev: Widen[M]): M[B] = ev.widen[A, B](ma)
  }
  // implicit class OpsNothing[M[_]](ma: M[Nothing]) {
  //   def widen[B](implicit ev: Widen[M]): M[B] = ev.widen(ma)
  // }
  implicit val WidenList = new Widen[List] { def widen[A, B >: A](l: List[A]): List[B] = l }
}

import Widen._

List.empty[Some[Int]].widen[Option[Int]]

List.empty[Nothing].widen[Int] // does not compile until uncommenting OpsNothing
```

But the last line does not compile. It seems to be related to partial unification because `new Widen.Ops[List, Nothing](List.empty[Nothing]).widen[Int]` does compile.

Now what's really weird is that if I uncomment the special case for `Nothing` then everything compiles.

I have no idea what's going on...

(This is using Scala 2.13.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler doesn't like to infer `Nothing` while resolving implicits

[Failed implicit resolution for Nothing with <:<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951621/failed-implicit-resolution-for-nothing-with)

Another workaround besides `OpsNothing` is type `Bottom`

```
type Bottom <: Nothing
List.empty[Bottom].widen[Int] // compiles
```