# Encoding Decoding a field with any datatype assigned with value None in Scala

Tags: json, scala, codec, encoder, circe

I am writing to write encoder/decoder for Any.
So suppose my class is

```
case class Demo(
field1: Any
)
```

and then I try to encoder it via

```
val myDemo=Demo(field1=None)
print(myDemo.asJson+"\n")
```

I have definded encoder decoder as

```
  implicit val valueEncoderValue: Encoder[Any] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Any](x=>{
    x.toString})

  implicit val valueDecoderValue: Decoder[Any] = Decoder.decodeString.map[Any](x => {
    if (x == "Any")
      x.asInstanceOf[Any]
    else
      x.toString
  })

  implicit lazy val DemoCodec: Codec[Demo] =
    deriveCodec[Demo]
```

I am getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class scala.None$ cannot be cast to class shapeless.labelled$KeyTag (scala.None$ and shapeless.labelled$KeyTag are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at TestDataCodecs$anon$lazy$macro$19$2$$anon$10.encodeObject(TestDataCodecs.scala:62)
    at TestDataCodecs$anon$lazy$macro$19$2$$anon$10.encodeObject(TestDataCodecs.scala:62)
    at io.circe.generic.codec.DerivedAsObjectCodec$$anon$1.encodeObject(DerivedAsObjectCodec.scala:21)
    at io.circe.Encoder$AsObject.apply(Encoder.scala:826)
    at io.circe.Encoder$AsObject.apply$(Encoder.scala:826)
    at io.circe.generic.codec.DerivedAsObjectCodec.apply(DerivedAsObjectCodec.scala:6)
    at io.circe.syntax.package$EncoderOps$.asJson$extension(package.scala:10)
    at MyClass$.main(test.scala:171)
    at MyClass.main(test.scala)
```

Seems pretty simple encoder decoder I dont understamd the cause of this error. Can anyone help define encoder decoder for this in scala

My depedencies file:

```
"io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.13.0",
"io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.13.0",
"io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.13.0",
"io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % "0.13.0",
"com.typesafe.akka"     %% "akka-http"         %  "10.2.4"
```

Comment: _"I am writing to write encoder/decoder for Any"_ - Don't do this, ever. - The main reason for using a typeclass is to ensure at compile time that whatever you are trying to encode / decode makes sense.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez True but well-written implicits/macros shouldn't throw ClassCastException/NullPointerException anyway :)

Comment: @DmytroMitin sure as well as runtime reflection, you will get an error eventually at runtime not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate how implicits are resolved now with `reify {...}` or `-Xprint:typer`. Then it will be seen what causes `ClassCastException`.

[In scala 2 or 3, is it possible to debug implicit resolution process in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime)

I haven't investigated yet how implicits are resolved now. Below is just what I think so far.

Firstly, when you define `Encoder[Any]` you define an encoder literally for everything.
And you define it locally, so this is a high-priority implicit, which fits for everything.
Apparently, this breaks something in Circe machinery. `shapeless.labelled.KeyTag` starts to be encoded not as expected etc.

Such implicits should be of low priority. Normally, implicits of low priority are defined with `LowPriority` pattern

```
trait LowPriority1 {
  // implicits
}
trait LowPriority extends LowPriority1 {
  // implicits
}
object CompanionObject extents LowPriority {
  // implicits
}
```

But you define it locally. It's tricky to define low-priority local implicits. For example you can use `shapeless.LowPriority`

```
implicit def valueEncoderValue(implicit lp: LowPriority): Encoder[Any] ...
```

Secondly, types `Nothing` and `Any` play special role in implicit resolution. Compiler tries to avoid to infer them during implicit resolution. You can check that even `AnyRef` can improve the situation. Workarounds are to use `type T <: Nothing` and similarly we can try `type T >: Any`.

[Failed implicit resolution for Nothing with <:<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951621/failed-implicit-resolution-for-nothing-with)

Thirdly, when you define a type `A`, normally the best place for implicits `Encoder[A]`, `Decoder[A]`, `Codec[A]` are in the companion object of `A`. This can improve automatic/semi-automatic derivation.

So as a workaround try

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder
import io.circe.Encoder
import shapeless.LowPriority
import io.circe.syntax._

type T >: Any
case class Demo(
                 field1: T
               )

val myDemo = Demo(field1 = None)
print(myDemo.asJson+"\n")

object Demo {
  implicit val DemoCodec: Encoder[Demo] = deriveEncoder[Demo]
}

implicit def valueEncoderValue(implicit lp: LowPriority): Encoder[T] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[T](x=>{
  x.toString})
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/gaZw3M0zQ6qwNwhqD1nq5g/1

Generally, defining `Encoder[Any]` looks weird. This looks like kind of abusing type-based codec derivation.

---

`-Xprint:typer` shows that `deriveCodec[Demo]` and `myDemo.asJson` are resolved in the following way

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/gaZw3M0zQ6qwNwhqD1nq5g/3

---

I was debugging and found the reasons for runtime exceptions. `ClassCastException` is because `shapeless.labelled.KeyTag` is a trait rather than an abstract type. Normally this works but not for `Any`. Not sure whether this is a bug. https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/1285

```scala
type FieldType[K, +V] = V with KeyTag[K, V]
trait KeyTag[K, +V] 

trait Tagged[U]
type @@[+T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

None.asInstanceOf[FieldType[Symbol @@ "field1", Any]]
// scala.None$ cannot be cast to KeyTag
```

```scala
type FieldType[K, +V] = V with KeyTag[K, V]
type KeyTag[K, +V] 

trait Tagged[U]
type @@[+T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

None.asInstanceOf[FieldType[Symbol @@ "field1", Any]] // no exception
```

You can try patched versions of Shapeless and Circe-generic with `KeyTag` being an abstract type rather than trait

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.10"
resolvers ++= Resolver.sonatypeOssRepos("releases")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core"   % "0.14.3",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.14.3",
  "com.github.dmytromitin" %% "circe-generic-patched-type-keytag" % "0.14.3",
  // "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.14.3" exclude("com.chuusai", "shapeless_2.13"),
  "com.github.dmytromitin" %% "shapeless-patched-type-keytag" % "2.3.10",
  // "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10",
)
```

https://github.com/DmytroMitin/shapeless-circe-patched-type-keytag

Then your code throws `NullPointerException` (`ClassCastException` is already fixed)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  case class Demo(
                   field1: Any
                 )

  val myDemo = Demo(field1 = None)
  print(myDemo.asJson + "\n")

  implicit val valueEncoderValue: Encoder[Any] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Any](x => {
    x.toString
  })

  implicit val valueDecoderValue: Decoder[Any] = Decoder.decodeString.map[Any](x => {
    if (x == "Any")
      x.asInstanceOf[Any]
    else
      x.toString
  })

  implicit lazy val DemoCodec: Codec[Demo] =
    deriveCodec[Demo]
}
```

`NullPointerException` is because of the initialization order in the object. You can check that

```scala
val myDemo = Demo(field1 = None)
implicit val valueEncoderValue: Encoder[Any] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Any](_.toString)
implicit val DemoCodec: Codec[Demo] = deriveCodec[Demo]
print(myDemo.asJson + "\n")
//{
//  "field1" : "None"
//}
```

works properly but

```scala
val myDemo = Demo(field1 = None)
implicit val valueEncoderValue: Encoder[Any] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Any](_.toString)
print(myDemo.asJson + "\n")
implicit val DemoCodec: Codec[Demo] = deriveCodec[Demo]
```

or

```scala
val myDemo = Demo(field1 = None)
implicit val DemoCodec: Codec[Demo] = deriveCodec[Demo]
print(myDemo.asJson + "\n")
implicit val valueEncoderValue: Encoder[Any] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Any](_.toString)
```

throw `NullPointerException`. The thing is that an implicit (a `val`) is used when in the object it's not initialized yet. A solution is to use `lazy val`

```scala
print(myDemo.asJson + "\n")
lazy val myDemo = Demo(field1 = None)
implicit lazy val DemoCodec: Codec[Demo] = deriveCodec[Demo]
implicit lazy val valueEncoderValue: Encoder[Any] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Any](_.toString)
```

Comment: Hi I am not able to define type T >: Any when the package name is given. I am getting error "Wrong top statement declaration"

Comment: [T >: Any] using this fixes the issues case class Demo[T >: Any]

Comment: @Dymtro Can you help me with this:

I am not able to define type T >: Any when the package name is given for the class. I am getting error "Wrong top statement declaration"

Comment: @Freez Abstract-type declarations can't be top-level. Scastie wraps an input into some object. So you can consider my code as if everything is inside some object. If you need to have an abstract type on top level I guess you can emulate this putting it into a package object.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/C0FHVzqOQOu1Rw6bcRiFbg https://github.com/DmytroMitin/shapeless-circe-patched-type-keytag

Comment: @Freez I was debugging and found the reasons for runtime exceptions. See the update.